# Create a unique page for each row in php and phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing a sort of messaging code. On the main page (page1.php) it displays all the messages you have got in a table with two columns(Who sent the message and Subject). When you click the Subject it's supposed to get the MESSAGE ID in the database and send you to a new page where you can read the message.

In the Page1.php there's this code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            echo "<tr><td>". $row["from"]." </td><td> <a href='lermsg.php?id = ".$row['idmsg']."'> ". $row["assunto"] ." </a> </td></tr>";


        }
```

The `$row[idmsg]` is supposed to send the ID value to the next page - lermsg.php

Now, the lermsg.php page:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

if( isset($_GET['lermsg'])){

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM msg WHERE 'idmsg' = '".$id."' LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
}else
{
    echo "  ERROR ";
}
```

The output:
     Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTEPHP\lermsg.php on line 9

```
 ERROR
```

and i'm getting this as URL:  `http://localhost/file/lermsg.php?id%20=%201` instead of id=1

The real_scape_string thing is something i have read somewhere and just tried since anything else seems to work. Also, i'm not sure how to properly use ' ' and " " on page1.php. I tried all possibles ways and nothing.

I know it's all confusing, but I'm really tired right now, but thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the spaces in your URL.

Comment: Thanks. now the id=1 is working,but i keep getting that ECHO message "ERROR", does it mean the the isset($_GET['lermsg'] is not working, or typep wrong?

Comment: Well, your URL doesn't have a `lermsg=___` parameter...

Comment: Nevermind. I get it. I changed the 'lermsg' between [ ] to 'id' forgot that. But now i added `$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  echo $result['assunto']; ` within the IF statement and it's not being printed

Comment: Oh dear. You obviously have problems in your code. Try `var_dump`ing some stuff.

Comment: *"I know it's all confusing, but I'm really tired right now"* --- So get some sleep. You'll be more productive after a good night's sleep, *believe me*. You'll most likely figure it out an hour after your first cup of coffee ;-) Just figure out where the spaces are coming from. `%20` is a space.